# Angular - Waiting until ngIf is ready to avoid undefined error for elementRef inside it

Tags: angular, rxjs

The input element is undefined after `inputVisibleIfThisIsTrue = true` because it is inside an `ngIf`, I could use a delay but what if use transitions and effects I don't want to worry about how much time the delay is set to.

```
if (this.something) {
    this.inputVisibleIfThisIsTrue = true;
    this.input.nativeElement.focus(); // this.input is undefined because ngIf takes time
}
```

So how can I only use `this.input.nativeElement.focus()` when the `ngIf` is ready? Is there an event that an observer could subscribe to?

Comment: Is this code something that you've written in `ngAfterViewInit`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook from Angular to perform functions after the view is fully initialized.
Take a look [here](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked) for the documentation of the hook and [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for other lifecycle hooks should you ever need them.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments on Korfoo's answer, I think what you're doing is:

```
if (this.something) {
  this.inputVisibleIfThisIsTrue = true;
  if (this.input !== undefined) {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

You can further simplify it by doing this:

```
if (this.something) {
  this.inputVisibleIfThisIsTrue = true;
  this.input && this.input.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: Oh no I put that code in the ngAfterViewChecked(), so whenever the view changes I check if it is undefined, it will be undefined if the container ngIf="false". I need the input focused as soon as it is visible.

Comment: Okay. Just wanted to add to that approach, that the second code snippet would be a short-hand syntax for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the more direct way with setTimeout right after the condition has changed.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epfwea

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a template variable to it: `<your-component-name #var>`
2. Query that variable with `@ContentChild`:

   ```
   @ContentChild('var', { read: ElementRef }) set _method(el: ElementRef) {
      // the component has been initializated, you can now access the variable el
   }
   ```

The difference between this solution and `AfterViewChecked` is that this solution works also for dynamically injected components or elements added at runtime, and you are sure the method is executed only if **that** element changed